# Calling Toast method inside onSuccess

Tags: android, api, android-asynctask, background-process, android-toast

I'm implementing a broadcast receiver which reads the incoming SMS. After that I'm calling an API which works fine. When iI get the response I want to show a toast message on the screen(onSuccess) from the onSuccess method.

I have tried a few iterations but nothing is working out.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//other code...

new NetworkAccess().execute(url); => Calling NetworkAccess, Passsing the URL here. //
```

}

```
public class NetworkAccess extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

          // API call here //

         public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {  
             // Toast Message goes here//

        }
        });
        return null;
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
```

}

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Make constructor and pass context into it.

```
public class NetworkAccess extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    private Context mContext;

    public NetworkAccess(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //API call goes here//
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,   JSONObject response) {
         Toast.makeText(mContext, "Your message goes here.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //API response comes here. I want to send an alert to the user after reading the response.//
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dhaval, I implemented the code and called the NetworkAccess class in this way new NetworkAccess(context).execute(hyperlink); in the Broadcast receiver. It's still not showing up the Toast Message. Any other suggestion?